# How to extract features from URLs in python?

Tags: python, url, machine-learning, classification

I have just started work on a classification project which detects phishing websites. I am using uci dataset https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00327/Training%20Dataset.arff.
I am trying several models on it like ANN, SVM, logistic regression and I have trained and tested the model.

My logistic regression code looks like this

```
#importing libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv("phishcoop.csv")
x = dataset.iloc[: , :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1]

#Split the dataset into training and test
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25, 
train_size =0.75, random_state = 0)

#fitting logistic regression into training set
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state =0)
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)

#Predicting values for test data
y_pred = classifier.predict(x_test)

#checking accurancy using confusion matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

How do I extract the 30 features in my dataset from the url which the user will give as input?

Comment: Did you look at using https://pypi.org/project/liac-arff/ ?

Comment: I have converted my dataset to csv

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html then perhaps? Python has builtin csv parsing.

Comment: If you're not asking how to extract features from the dataset, then what is your question? What is the "url which the user will give as input"? Are you trying to parse that URL? Parse the file which is pointed to by that URL? If the latter you don't say what type of file it is.

Comment: I have 30 attributes in my dataset (link is in question). I wants to apply the model in real life where user will give url by input and we will extract these attributes from the url for exp. - having_ip, url_length, Prefix_Suffix etc. and predict whether that url have a phishing website or not. I wants to ask that is there any library which will help me in this or what is the best approach to extract these attributes from the given url

Comment: It sounds like you're just trying to parse a url and not the contents of the target of the url. I've written an answer for this.

Comment: No, there is not any library for that. You need to do that yourself. This question is very broad. You need to write the code for that and come here if finding any difficulties in getting the results for that. The docx you linked in the below answer has the process, you just need to convert that to code.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you just want to parse a URL. Then grab the IP for the hostname supplied perhaps.

For python 3 (For Python 2 see how to import here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
import socket


url = 'http://example.com/x/y?a=1&b=2'

# Parse the URL
parsed = urlparse('http://example.com/x/y?a=1&b=2&a=3')

# For the parameters
params = parse_qs(parsed.query)
print(params)

# For path components
# Note: Depending on the URL, this may have empty strings so that's why the
# filter is used
path_components = list(filter(bool, parsed.path.split('/')))
print(path_components)

# Location
print(parsed.netloc)

# IP
print(socket.gethostbyname(parsed.netloc))
```

Will output this:

```
{'a': ['1', '3'], 'b': ['2']}
['x', 'y']
example.com
93.184.216.34
```

Comment: can you have a look at this https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00327/Phishing%20Websites%20Features.docx , It describe the features that I want to extract from url. Thanks for helping

Comment: urllib will definitely help me to extract some of attributes

Comment: What type of features are these? E.g. One of the listed features is "Using the IP Address". Is this supposed to be a boolean or just the value of the `netloc` which might be "example.com" or "93.184.216.34".

Comment: Actually, looking at https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00327/Training%20Dataset.arff I see that they seem to be encoded as `(-1, 0, 1). So it looks like you might have to generate that encoding yourself with various tests (e.g. testing if the netloc is an ip or not). Unless the original authors have code to achieve that you can use. It also looks like they examine the behaviour of following the url as well as the url itself.

Comment: I am not an expert on machine learning, but I also think you probably need to be careful with encoding as `(-1, 0, 1)` as a three-valued logic as this could imply that the average of -1 and 1 is 0. Which by the look of these features, is not the case. one-hot-encoding or making sure they are treated as categorical is probably wise.

Comment: yes I'll have to encode them by myself, urllib will help me to get some of them but some of them are complex, if there is any library that will make the task easy ? I will definitely look at one hot encoder. Thanks

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Some of them will require requesting the url and examining what happens to determine if there were redirects, etc. Some will require parsing the HTML at the URL (I recommend https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). The authors must have code to do this if they built a dataset, so if it's not public, you might want to contact them to see if they could make it so.